# import com.google.android.gcm cannot be resolved in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I wanted to use GCM Push Notifications in my Android App which I am developing in Eclipse.

I have updated my SDK Tools as you can see in the uploaded picture.

I still cant find any jars in extras/google/

How can I download the required jars and add them to my project?

My Android SDK Manager:
[image]

Comment: Use Android Studio. Eclipse is not an officially supported GUI by Google.

Comment: Are you using gradle?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the gcm library try import the existing project from the directory directly from

Android_SDK_Location\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib

Use it as a library project.
Just remind you that now google provided the Firebase for the push notification which needs to use firebase sdk.
FYR: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

and i think the question may be duplicated?